# Error in YAML with R Markdown

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, opencpu

I have the following R Markdown script called `test.Rmd`:

````
---
params: 
  results: 
  value: !r mtcars
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
df <- params$results
knitr::kable(df)
```
````

When I run the following in OpenCPU:

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", output_format = "html_document")
```

> Error in yaml::yaml.load(yaml, handlers = knit_params_handlers(evaluate = evaluate),  : 
>          unused argument (eval.expr = TRUE)

I installed different versions of YAML and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Can you refine the question as it is currently difficult to work out where this could be going wrong. Some tips: 1) Use a dataset which others can recreate such as the `mtcars` dataset.  2) Does the 'EXPORT' function need to be defined or can you just run the `render` functions normally? 3) Change the file path to remove the `system.file` path and just create a relative path. In doing these changes, you may even discover the problem yourself.

Comment: See my edits. By my understanding that should still show the error you are seeing. If it is not correct though, rollback the changes.

Comment: Yes it throw the same error, even without the parameter: `params = list(results = mtcars)`. If i write in the R markdown script `params: 
  results: !r mtcars` and i execute `rmarkdown::render("mtcarsexample.Rmd", output_format = "html_document")` i get the same error

Comment: Okay, I further edited your question. Please use this as an example of how to slim-down your questions in the future :) Are you sure all your packages are up to date? `install.packages("rmarkdown")` etc.

Comment: Yes thx!!!
Finally I have solved it.
My installation of the yaml-2.1.14 package was corrupted. I have had to delete it manually and I have installed version 2.1.19.
Since the latest version 2.2.0. also gave me problems

Answer (score 2):

I took a while to fix this as well. It seems the new `knitr` needs a version of `yaml` 2.2.0 and above.

This help from @ScientificProgrammer on github here https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/issues/56#issuecomment-441394840 helped me. The solution was to install the new package using devtools from within **standard R not RStudio**. I did get some compiler error messages but it seemed to work. So don't let that put you off.

So inside Standard R assuming you have the `devtools` package

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("viking/r-yaml")
```

I am copying their answer over in full below to help people in case the link breaks:

> In case it helps, I was having the same problem as IndrajeetPatil when
>   I tried to run devtools::install_github("viking/r-yaml") from within
>   RStudio. If I ran install.packages("viking/r-yaml") from within
>   RStudio, the problem was resolved.
>
> However, when I exited RStudio and ran
>   devtools::install_github("viking/r-yaml") from within the standard R
>   client, I still received the same compiler warnings, but the problem
>   also went away.

P.S. Another popular solution that helped some people was to delete the `yaml` directory completely e.g. using Windows Explorer. Restart RStudio Ctrl + Shift + F10, and then re-install yaml package. That did not work for me as it kept giving me just 2.1.18 version.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the devtools package from CRAN.
2. In R, run the following:

   library(devtools)

   install_github('viking/r-yaml')

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer will be most useful if you explain it more completely.

Comment: Attempted to `install_github('viking/r-yaml')`, which not only failed, but has now apparently corrupted by RStudio installation so that on startup, I get `Error in .Call(C_unserialize_from_yaml, string, as.named.list, handlers,  : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (8), expecting 4 for 'unserialize_from_yaml'` multiple times. I also seem to be unable to reinstall the original `yaml`. More explanation to the answer would have been good.